# How to enable autoformating Flutter project in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

For example, there is a sample flutter code. This code is not properly formatted.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(SampleApp());

class SampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            child: const Text('123'),), // this line isn't properly formatted 
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've heard that Android Studio is able to autoformat flutter code when a code saved in editor. In that case, certain conditions had to be respected, - all the commas should be present in code like it is in the above sample code. But I didn't find how to do that. So if it's true (i.e. if it's possible to do that) how to achive that?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Go to **Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Flutter** and check **Format code on save**.

---

You can also use Reformat code [shortcut](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts) manually:

Windows/Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Mac: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

Here's step:

For Android Studio Windows:

`File`>`Settings`>`Languages ​​& Frameworks`>`Flutter`>Check `Format code on save`

For Android Studio Macbook:

`Android Studio` (Left File)>`Settings`>`Languages ​​& Frameworks`>`Flutter`>Check `Format code on save`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> Windows, <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> Mac to Save auto format!

Comment: For some reason this setting is on for me but it's not working. Ctrl + Alt + L works tough. Any idea why auto format on save isn't working?

Answer (score 2):

As @janstol said, there is a shortcut to auto reformat code. However, I had the same problem but I could not solve it because my command was not established, so I'll leave the route to get there in case someone needs it.

Open **Setting > Preferences > Keymap** and search for the one that says "**Reformat code with 'dart format'**". There you can customize it as needed.